# How to draw a line over an image in android with zoom in & out and dragging

Tags: android

I am working on a concept that I have to draw a line over SurfaceView and want to drag, zoom in & zoom out as well as movement of that line according to image movement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the canvas, paint, and path classes in the android API.

Comment: Thank you. I've solved the problem using android.graphics.matrix. And the drawing shapes according to this matrix (Bitmap, circle, line .. etc) using RectF:
RectF r = new RectF();matrix.mapRect(r);

Comment: I just face some problems in zooming. I can zoom the image but not the shapes drawn on it. Here is the code:
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   Paint p = new Paint();
   canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
   RectF r = new RectF();
   matrix.mapRect(r);
   System.out.println(r.width());
   canvas.drawBitmap(mapImg, r.left, r.top, p);
}